# How to take screen shot of a area that ignores your applications window on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, screenshot

I am trying to make something like pixie app on Mac OS X. I am doing this by taking screenshot of a region around my mouse and putting the screenshot in an image view.

```
image = CGDisplayCreateImageForRect(displays[i],
                                    CGRectMake(x_start, y_start, width, height));
```

the problem is,  its also capturing the window of my application. How can I take a screen shot that treats my application's window as transparent, and only takes whats behind my apps window

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `CGWindowListCreateImage` and set your own window's `sharingType` to `NSWindowSharingNone` (so that it'll be skipped in the screenshot). I'm not sure if this method will be fast enough for your purposes though.

Comment: Look at the SonOfGrab sample.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score -3):

You can easily take a screenshot of any unwanted or wanted area on mac by these short cut key. These keys will really help you in any capturing shot on Mac.

Just simply press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> and take then the available cross hairs anywhere you want to take screenshot.